# Power BI Report Builder Parameters Type mismatch error

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I'm building a paginated report on Power BI Report builder using an SSAS cube as my data source. I'm having issues with some of my parameters. If I select ALL or just one value I don't get an error, but when I select two or more values it throws me the following error:

### The following system error occurred:  Type mismatch.

### Query execution failed for dataset 'JIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME'.

### An error has occurred during report processing.

An error occurred during local report processing.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I've been looking all over the place and I can't find a solution.

Thank you,

```
DEFINE VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY) = 1, IF(@JIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY <> "", @JIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY, BLANK()), IF(PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY, 2), BLANK()))
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY) > 1 && PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY, 1, 1) < 1
VAR vFromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@FromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI) = 1, IF(@FromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI <> "", @FromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI, BLANK()), IF(PATHITEM(@FromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@FromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI, 2), BLANK()))
VAR vFromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@FromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI) > 1 && PATHITEM(@FromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI, 1, 1) < 1
VAR vToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@ToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI) = 1, IF(@ToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI <> "", @ToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI, BLANK()), IF(PATHITEM(@ToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@ToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI, 2), BLANK()))
VAR vToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@ToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI) > 1 && PATHITEM(@ToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI, 1, 1) < 1
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME) = 1, IF(@JIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME <> "", @JIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME, BLANK()), IF(PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME, 2), BLANK()))
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME) > 1 && PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME, 1, 1) < 1
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME) = 1, IF(@JIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME <> "", @JIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME, BLANK()), IF(PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME, 2), BLANK()))
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME) > 1 && PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME, 1, 1) < 1
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY) = 1, IF(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY <> "", @JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY, BLANK()), IF(PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY, 2), BLANK()))
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY) > 1 && PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY, 1, 1) < 1
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE) = 1, IF(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE <> "", @JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE, BLANK()), IF(PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE, 2), BLANK()))
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE) > 1 && PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE, 1, 1) < 1
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY1 = IF(PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY) = 1, IF(@JIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY <> "", @JIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY, BLANK()), IF(PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY, 2) <> "", PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY, 2), BLANK()))
VAR vJIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY1ALL = PATHLENGTH(@JIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY) > 1 && PATHITEM(@JIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY, 1, 1) < 1
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('JIRA UCM Incidents'[REPORT_DATE_ASIA_DUBAI], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[CASE_ID], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[ORDER_ID], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[ORDER_DATE_ASIA_DUBAI], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[ORDER_PUNCHED_BY], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[ORDER_STATUS], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[AFFECTED_ITEM_NAME], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[REPORTER_NAME], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[COUNTRY], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[ORG_SOURCE], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[BRAND_NAME], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[KITCHEN_NAME], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[INCIDENT_CATEGORY], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[INCIDENT_TYPE], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[RESPONSIBLE_PARTY], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[WRONG_PUNCH_TYPE], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[JIRA_CREATED_DATE_ASIA_DUBAI], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[REFUND_AMOUNT], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[COMPLAINT_DETAILS], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[COMPLAINT_RESOLUTION], 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[SUMMARY], FILTER(VALUES('JIRA UCM Incidents'[COUNTRY]), ((vJIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY1ALL || 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[COUNTRY] = vJIRAUCMIncidentsCOUNTRY1))), FILTER(VALUES('JIRA UCM Incidents'[REPORT_DATE_ASIA_DUBAI]), (vFromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1ALL || 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[REPORT_DATE_ASIA_DUBAI] >= DATEVALUE(vFromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1) + TIMEVALUE(vFromJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1)) && (vToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1ALL || 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[REPORT_DATE_ASIA_DUBAI] <= DATEVALUE(vToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1) + TIMEVALUE(vToJIRAUCMIncidentsREPORTDATEASIADUBAI1))), FILTER(VALUES('JIRA UCM Incidents'[BRAND_NAME]), ((vJIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME1ALL || 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[BRAND_NAME] = vJIRAUCMIncidentsBRANDNAME1))), FILTER(VALUES('JIRA UCM Incidents'[KITCHEN_NAME]), ((vJIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME1ALL || 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[KITCHEN_NAME] = vJIRAUCMIncidentsKITCHENNAME1))), FILTER(VALUES('JIRA UCM Incidents'[INCIDENT_CATEGORY]), ((vJIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY1ALL || 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[INCIDENT_CATEGORY] = vJIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTCATEGORY1))), FILTER(VALUES('JIRA UCM Incidents'[INCIDENT_TYPE]), ((vJIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE1ALL || 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[INCIDENT_TYPE] = vJIRAUCMIncidentsINCIDENTTYPE1))), FILTER(VALUES('JIRA UCM Incidents'[RESPONSIBLE_PARTY]), ((vJIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY1ALL || 'JIRA UCM Incidents'[RESPONSIBLE_PARTY] = vJIRAUCMIncidentsRESPONSIBLEPARTY1))))
```

i didnt find a solution